# Confusion on promise objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

I've read about promise objects and infact have worked on promise objects but still I must say I'm not clear on the basics.

```
$http.get('/someURL').then(function(response) {
// do something
}, function(error) {
});
```

People say that .then returns a promise object. In the above example $http.get() returns a promise object. So what does this line mean? Does it mean promise.promise?? (promise object returned by $http.get() dot promise returned by .then)?

Can anyone please clarify?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$http.get()` returns a promise.  You can then call `.then()` on that promise.  `.then()` returns yet another promise that you aren't actually using in your code.

For example, you could do this:

```
var p = $http.get('/someURL').then(function(response) {
    // do something
}, function(error) {
    // do something on error
});

// p is a promise
p.then(function() {
    // more code here that runs after the previous code
});
```

Or, you could do:

```
$http.get('/someURL').then(function(response) {
    // do something
}, function(error) {
    // do something on error
}).then(function() {
    // more code here
});
```

So, each `.then()` handler returns yet another promise so you can chain as many times as you want.  One particularly useful feature is that if you return a promise from a `.then()` handler callback, then the promise that the `.then()` handler already returned will inherit that promise you return from the callback like this:

```
$http.get('/someURL').then(function(response) {
    return $http.get('/someOtherURL');
}, function(error) {
    // do something on error
}).then(function(secondResponse) {
    // will get here when both http.get operations are done
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I think I understand what it means now. And my another question is, what would be the initial value of the var p??

Is it an empty json returned by $http.get() before the http GET request and later overridden by the actual response object?

Comment: `p` is a promise object. It is initially in the `pending` state (not yet resolved and has no internal value yet).  Then, when the the http operations complete, they `resolve` the promise and it moves to the `Fulfilled` state and calls its `.then()` handlers and passes them the resolved value.  Promise are objects with methods and some internal state.

Comment: @DilipBS-You can think of a promise like this. I'm going to run an http request that will finish some time later. So, I get a bucket and I instruct the http request to deposit its result in the bucket when its done. I instruct any outsiders that if they want to know when the http request is done, then register yourself with the bucket and it will call you when the results are done.  I then tell the bucket that when the http response is dropped into the bucket, it should call each of the outsiders that asked for notification and pass it the response that was dropped in. The bucket is a promise.

Comment: @DilipBS - cont'd - `.then()` handlers are the way you register bucket notifications.

Comment: That's really awesome. Your further explanations helped me to understand a lot.

Answer (score 2):

One of the cool features of promises is that they can be linked together.  The $http.get() returns a promise which you have called the then on.  That then also returns a promise and allows you to do additional things in another then statement.  For instance:

```
function myGet() {
    return $http.get('myRoute').then(
        function(res) {
           //do something
           return res;
        }, function(err) {
           return $q.reject(err);
        });  
}

myGet().then(
    function(res) {
        //Do something else
    }, function(err) {
        //Handle Error
    });
```

This can be very handy if you want to have a procedure happen after the myGet function either is succesful or has an error.